# How to use WebP image in UIImageView Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, webp

I want to use webp image in UIImageView my ios project which is in Swift Language.

I tried using [Matt Thompson library](https://github.com/mattt/WebPImageSerialization)
but it's not working with Swift project. 
I have imported the framework and did all required tasks but so many link errors.

How can I use webp Image in UIImageView in swift code?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the Pod https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

There is it really easy to load WebP Images from the Web

With Swift:

```
SDWebImageManager.shared().loadImage(with: url, options: .highPriority, progress: nil, completed: {(resultSet) in
            YOURWEBVIEW.image = resultSet.0

        })
```

Answer (score 5):

**2019 SWIFT 5**

I use [SDWebImageWebPCoder](https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImageWebPCoder) and it works like magic.

Here is how to use it: -

```
  let webPCoder = SDImageWebPCoder.shared
    SDImageCodersManager.shared.addCoder(webPCoder)
    guard let webpURL = URL(string: webpUrlString)  else {return}
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        imageView.sd_setImage(with: webpURL)
    }
```